# Designing Quiz App for flexibility questionTypes

Tags: objective-c, ios, dynamic

I am creating a quiz app that uses a `ViewController` named `QuestionViewController` to load and display the question data from a custom `Question` class. Right now, I am just checking the `questionType` of to determine how the `Answer` children of the `Question` need to be displayed. Then I have many if/then statements to display the `answerTypes` which can be:

- buttonType (radio/checkbox)
- inputFieldType
- datePickerType
- (any other types)

This works ok, but it's really sloppy. I would like to load the `Question` then find the type of question using if/then in which **I believe I should create custom view controller** for each questionType and display that and **maybe add protocols to return when the input has changed**. Is this the right way to do this? I'd like to keep question types as dynamic as possible so I can add future types should we need them.

Am I on the right track? Is there something I'm missing/should improve on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like you are on the right track.  One thing to keep in mind though is that your questions will ALL likely have to do a few things the same, such as... display the question!  This lends itself well to subclassing as follows:

`UIViewController` -> `QuestionViewController` -> `CustomQuestionViewController1`
`UIViewController` -> `QuestionViewController` -> `CustomQuestionViewController2`
`UIViewController` -> `QuestionViewController` -> `CustomQuestionViewController3`

etc.

Every `Question` will have to have certain information to display regardless of the question/answer type.  For example, it is likely that every one of your questions will have some sort of `UILabel` or `UITextView` displaying the text for the question.  This label's position, font, etc. will probably not change from question to question, so it should be setup in the question's `QuestionViewController`, where as the answers (whose format will likely vary, as you mention) can be setup in the various `CustomQuestionViewController`s that you implement.  This will greatly reduce potential code duplication in your question's view controllers because the things they do the same can be done inside your `QuestionViewController`.

If you did your subclassing like below...

`UIViewController` -> `CustomQuestionViewController1`

`UIViewController` -> `CustomQuestionViewController2`

You would likely end up with a lot of duplicate code setting up the basic question display.

Also, name them better than `CustomQuestionViewController1` haha.

Comment: Thanks, and good point about subclassing the `QuestionViewController`

Comment: Np.  In terms of adding those protocols... it really depends on what benefit you think they may grant you.  It also depends on how the users are permitted to navigate the Quiz.  Can they go backward, forward, re-answer, etc. in any way they please?  Are future quiz questions dependent on previous quiz questions?  How are the user's answers stored?  Are they stored inside the Answer class, or is there a separate class for storing these?  Based on the answers to some of these questions, you can determine if those protocols would be useful to you or not.